# I can't do "git push -u origin main" to remote repo

Tags: github, gatsby, git-push

I'm begineer for learning programming.
I did this tutorial for learning Gatsby.
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/getting-started/part-1/#set-up-a-github-repo-for-your-site

But I can't "git push -u origin main" to remote repo.

Below is the error message.

```
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/takagiyuuki/learning-gatsby.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Please teach me how I do that.

thanks.

1. deploy gatsby's web page on local
2. create new repo in Github
3. To push my existing code from my computer  <-- error is happen

executed commannd:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/YOUR_GITHUB_REPO_NAME.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```